PIP install Qi fails
I'm trying to install the python sdk for the qi framework using python3.
The documentation says to use python 2.7 with the naoqi library, but there was a release of the framework with python3 whose name is qi.
On PyPi (https://pypi.org/project/qi/#modal-close) the package is present, but when I run it on a virtalenv with python3.9 or other versions >= 3.5, on macos Sequoia I get this error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for qi

I don't know how to solve it.
